# Vim: Disable autocomplete in insert mode mapping

Tags: javascript, vim

I have this insert mode mapping to auto-indent brackets:

```
inoremap [;<CR> [<CR>];<Esc>O<Tab>
```

When I run it the result is the following (pipe char represents cursor):

```
const a = [
  |
];
```

I want to have an analogous mapping for parens, so I did:

```
inoremap (;<CR> (<CR>);<Esc>O<Tab>
```

This works if I run it on an unsaved buffer, but if Vim picks up the `.js` filetype, this is the result:

```
const a = (
      |
    );
```

How can I do this without autoindent kicking in?

Not sure if it matters, but I'm using YouCompleteMe with Tern for JavaScript autocompletion.

Comment: Try with `:set noautoindent` , `:set nocindent` , `:set nosmartindent`.

Comment: But how do I do that inside the `inoremap` statement? I need it to be off only while that command is being run. It should be re-enabled when it finishes.

Comment: Try with `:inoremap (;<CR> (<CR><Tab><CR>0<C-D>);<UP>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one-liner by [Meninx - メネンックス](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4392605/meninx-%e3%83%a1%e3%83%8d%e3%83%b3%e3%83%83%e3%82%af%e3%82%b9) worked:

```
:inoremap (;<CR> (<CR><Tab><CR>0<C-D>);<UP>
```